# SQL limit insert in a table if a row has a certain number of inserts already

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to limit an insert in a table if a row has already a certain numbers of references in that table. I have this table named generals_and_divisions that references other tables that is general and a table division, the table generals_and_divisions is a relashionship holder. I need to limit a insertion of relationship if a certain division is commanded by 3 generals already. A division can only be commanded by 3 generals at the same time, i need to block a insertion if a division already have 3 generals linked to him.

Here is my table code:

```
 CREATE TABLE generals_and_divisions(
 general_id INT NOT NULL,
 division_id INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_general_id` FOREIGN KEY (`general_id`) REFERENCES `general` (`general_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_division_id` FOREIGN KEY (`division_id`) REFERENCES `division` (`division_id`));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is non-trivial.

The simplest method is an `insert` trigger that counts the number of rows and does not allow an insert if there are already three rows.

Another method -- which I prefer -- is to put a counter in the `division` tables with the number of generals.  Then you can have a check constraint in the `division` table that limits the number to 3.  However, to maintain the count, you need triggers on the `generals_and_divisions` table.

A third method is to store the generals in the divisions table as `general1`, `general2`, and `general3`.  The data is not strictly in normal form but there is no way to have more than three generals.